# C# Create Variable names based on an incremental For Loop

Tags: c#

I am creating a JSON Object.
I want to achieve the below

I would want to make the name of the variable "item_1" dynamic.
So if there 3 items in the loop.
I should create item_1, item_2, item_3 etc

```
dynamic extension = new JObject();
dynamic item_1 = new JObject();
item_1.id = "00000000-0000-7000-0000-0000000c74c7";
item_1.risk_action = "Bind";
extension.Add(item_1);
```

How can i achieve the above in a for loop and create variable names dynamically and add it to the main json object

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You should consider an dictionary to implement such behavior

Answer (score 1):

C# is **strongly** typed so you can't create variables dynamically.

One way to solve it, is to use an array, or you could use a dictionary

look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0